# Start Address of dma region in arm64

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, arm, dma

On ARM 32-bit machines, the Start Address of DMA and size can be found from the variables 'atomic_pool' and 'atomic_pool_size' present in arch/arm/mm/dma-mapping.c file

I dont see the same variables in arm64 architecture in arch/arm/mm/dma-mapping.c file

How can i find out the Start Address and size of DMA

Comment: looks like the output of `arch_acpi_dma_setup` https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.18/source/drivers/acpi/arm64/dma.c#L7

Comment: Seems to be in "kernel/dma/pool.c", but there may be up to three pools depending on whether `CONFIG_ZONE_DMA` and/or `CONFIG_ZONE_DMA32` are enabled.